# Rudin's PMA: theorem 10.39

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

This theorem is used in the proof of our theorem.
[image]

Here is our  theorem and its proof :
[image]
[image]

My question is that, how are the representations of  $(118)$ and $(121)$ equal of each other?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (118), the summation is over all possible subsets of $\{1,\dots,p\}$, where I assume $dx_I$ is taken to mean $dx_{i_1} \wedge \dots \wedge dx_{i_k}$ and $\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}=I $.

In (121), $\alpha$ contains the subsets without $dx_p$, and the new summation contains all those with $dx_p$.

Comment: Thank you. @JMP

Comment: no problem! @NikaDevdariani